# Which is correct here: "arbitrary" or "arbitrarily"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs

Do you say "an arbitrarily small constant epsilon" or "an arbitrary small constant epsilon"? Or are both correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would say "an arbitrarily small constant epsilon" because *arbitrarily* is an adverb that modifies the adjective *small*. This is the usual meaning of the constant epsilon—that it can become as small as possible.

However, "an arbitrary small constant epsilon" has meaning in itself in the sense of a constant that is small and arbitrary. The word *small* would be then relative.

Comment: This is what I couldn't figure out... Good answer, +1.

Comment: 'Arbitrarily' is an adverb modifying an adjective, 'arbitrary' is an adjective.

Comment: After you introduce "an arbitrarily small constant epsilon" you may later remind the reader of its property by talking about "the arbitrary smallness of epsilon"... since now "arbitrary" is an adjective.